# How to remove rows with null values from kth column onward in python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to remove all rows in which elements from column 3 onwards are all NaN

```
df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 5), index=['a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g','h'], columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'])

df2 = df.reindex(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])
df2.ix[1][0] = 111
df2.ix[1][1] = 222
```

In the example above, my final data frame would not be having rows 'b' and 'c'.

How to use `df.dropna()` in this case?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can call [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with arguments `subset` and `how`:

```
df2.dropna(subset=['three', 'four', 'five'], how='all')
```

As the names suggests:

- `how='all'` requires every column (of `subset`) in the row to be `NaN` in order to be dropped, as opposed to the default `'any'`.
- `subset` is those columns to inspect for `NaN`s.

As [@PaulH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552748/paul-h) points out, we can generalise to drop the last `k` columns with:

```
subset=df2.columns[k:]
```

Indeed, we could even do something more complicated if desired:

```
subset=filter(lambda x: len(x) > 3, df2.columns)
```

Comment: perhaps `df2.dropna(subset=df2.columns[k:], how='all')`? (just to be more general)

Comment: @Thanks Paul. This is what I was looking for